Why does a conditional type infer a union of const string arrays, rather than a const string union array?
In this code:
interface Payload1<T> {
    data: T extends string ? T[] : T[]
}

interface Payload2<T> {
    data: T[]
}

const p1: Payload1<"red" | "blue"> = {
    data: ["red", "blue"]
}

const p2: Payload2<"red" | "blue"> = {
    data: ["red", "blue"]
}

p2 compiles because it deduces data: ("red" | "blue")[], but p1 does not, as ts determines data: "red"[] | "blue"[]. Why is this? If this is a bug, is there a simple workaround?

This is simply a distributive conditional type and there are plenty of questions this can be closed as a duplicate of. What are you trying to do here, if not interface Payload1<T> {data: T[]}?  Presumably by mixing this with your previous question you're looking for something like this playground link. Do you want to ask a question explicitly about that and then I'll answer it (although I guess you'll accept any answer to the same effect)? Or is something missing?
